# JQuery events firing once on load and not again

Tags: jquery

what I'm trying to achieve is to execute some code when an input field is changed.

Some context... the form's page is loaded within a light box (colorbox) using an iframe.

I'm experiencing two problems in one:

1. The change event fires when the form loads. It shouldn't - it should only fire when the field is changed. The same thing happens if I use other events such as focus or click. And it happens also if I use go, live or bind.
2. The change event (or focus, click, etc) does not fire then when the event actually occurs.

Both problems occur for document ready and load events.

For trouble shooting purposes I inserted a line that puts a value into the form field. That worked perfectly.

Here's the code example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inputfield").change(alert("field changed"));
}
```

In principle this should work so I'm assuming there's something else on the page affecting it but I've run out of places to look. Is event delegation a solution? I do not know how it would apply here.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you call function `change` with what function `alert` returns. So it cal `alert` function, it return `undefined` and you call `change(undefined)`. This way you don't bind an event at all. You should set as a parameter a function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inputfield").change(function () { 
    alert("field changed"); 
  });
}
```